# "Couldn't send a valid signature" error when using CloudKit

Tags: objective-c, cloudkit

Anyone know what could be causing this error which is returned in the query block below:

```
<CKError 0x7f8d5ba27a10: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't send a valid signature">
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [container publicCloudDatabase];

//CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:container] publicCloudDatabase];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"doctorName = %@", @"Dr. Harry White"];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"WellnessTest" predicate:predicate];

[publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.description);
    }
    else
    {
        // Display the fetched records
        NSLog(@"Results: %@", results.description);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On the iPhone/iPad simulator go to Settings > iCloud and then log in using your Apple ID.

Comment: Great thanks that solved my issue. Didnt know i could login to iCloud through the simulator.

Comment: shouldn't you be able to query the public database without logging in?

Comment: @Andy exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: A comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321975/couldnt-send-a-valid-signature-error-when-using-cloudkit-without-icloud-accou explains why this is needed.

Comment: @holmes Eternal gratitude to you, O Master :)

Comment: Anyone have any idea on this when you ARE logged into CloudKit (Simulator). This is with Xcode 9.  My simulator is logged in to CloudKit (and my check I do earlier to make sure they are logged in passes) but when I try and do a fetch I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing your app against CloudKit's Production environment, you may still have this error even if you have signed into iCloud on the simulator. In this case, running your app on a device would fix the error.